# Protocol for WPF User interface on remote machine

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, networking, ipc

I am currently working on a project where I have a .net application running on a server. This application will get commands from a User Interface in WPF which is running on a separate machine. These two machines are connected via Ethernet in a local network. The User Interface will get information from the backend server like current Color of a RGB Lamp and will be able to modify these values and send commands like "switch to Preset A".

So I thought about using Sockets with SSL, but what if the connection gets lost, how do I update the values, if they changed during disconnection and how do I handle an automatic reconnect etc.

Or might using REST or UDP better and just requesting an update from the backend regularily, so we dont have a continuous connection, but isn't that unnessesary traffic? Or should I even use OSC?

So in total, I want to build something like a remote control which also displays current information/values and which can handle disconnects safely.

Comment: the Application on the server should be a service (preferably web in which case IIS or what ever webserver your server is running will manage communication for you) then just connect your app to the service, trigger the Messages and monitor the responses. you could also just a push service like signalR for 2 way communication

Comment: What you are describing is called a Message Queue, there are many available such as [MSMQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms711472(v=vs.85).aspx) and [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/). Which is best for you depends on your requirements, which you have not told us.

Comment: I used Namedpipe with a small protocol, here you find a nice wrapper https://github.com/acdvorak/named-pipe-wrapper. The protocol you can define by your own and as your requirements mentioned is not so difficult